# What is the top-level "Desktop" explorer node that apears with the "Show all folders" option? All *which* folders?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, modern-ui

In the Windows 10 Explorer, if you are showing the Navigation (left) pane, and you (by any of several various methods) select "Show all folders", everything but the "Quick access" node gets placed under a new top-level node called "Desktop" along with some new stuff.

This new "Desktop" node only appears loosely connected with my Desktop (i.e. the contents of the background screen): things on my Desktop will appear, along with other stuff, in the right explorer pane when I select the top-level Desktop node in the left pane.

In particular, the right pane will show everything that is on my actual Desktop, along with all the immediate sub-nodes of Desktop that appear in the left pane. The only thing that appears in all 3 locations is the Recycle Bin.

This leaves me wondering what "Show all folders" means... all *what* folders? "all" is a big place. The only new folders are my home profile folder and Control Panel. New items in the right pane are the Desktop contents, but these aren't "folders" and the option didn't mention showing non-folder objects.

It looks like this option might be there to provide a way of getting at some stuff that became hard to reach once the Desktop interface was replaced with the Tile interface ("Modern UI"?). It seems to me, though, that is has a serious naming problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a virtual folder, the root of the [Shell Namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro). It contains file system items from your User's **Desktop** folder as well as the Public Desktop folder and virtual items such as **Control Panel**, **Recycle Bin**, **This PC**. The link explains it better than I can! :D

EDIT: Here's some **PowerShell** for John's sake...

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.Application

$Desktop = $Shell.Namespace(0)

$Desktop.Items() | select Name

$Desktop.Items() | ?{$_.IsFileSystem -match 'False'} | select Name, Type

$Desktop.Items() | ?{$_.Name -match 'Panel$'} | %{$_.GetFolder.Items() | select Name, Type, Path | fl}

$Desktop.Items() | ?{$_.Name -match 'Panel$'} | %{$_.GetFolder.Items()} | %{$_.GetFolder.Items() | select Name, Type, Path | fl}

#######################################################

>>>>>>>  Output from above <<<<<<<<<<<

PS C:\>>$Shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.Application
PS C:\> $Shell

Application        Parent
-----------        ------
System.__ComObject System.__ComObject


PS C:\>>$Desktop = $Shell.Namespace(0)
PS C:\>>$Desktop


Title                      : Desktop
Application                : System.__ComObject
Self                       : System.__ComObject
HaveToShowWebViewBarricade : False
ShowWebViewBarricade       : False

PS C:\>>$Desktop.Items() | select Name

Name
----
This PC
Recycle Bin
Renamed Control Panel
Keith Miller
Libraries
Control Panel
Network
...
iTunes


PS C:\>>$Desktop.Items() | ?{$_.IsFileSystem -match 'False'} | select Name, Type

Name                  Type
----                  ----
This PC               System Folder
Recycle Bin           System Folder
Renamed Control Panel System Folder
Libraries             System Folder
Control Panel         System Folder
Network               System Folder


PS C:\>>$Desktop.Items() | ?{$_.Name -match 'Panel$'} | %{$_.GetFolder.Items() | select Name, Type, Path | fl}


Name : System and Security
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\5

Name : Network and Internet
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\3

Name : Hardware and Sound
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\2

Name : Programs
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\8

Name : User Accounts
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\9

Name : Appearance and Personalization
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\1

Name : Clock and Region
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\6

Name : Ease of Access
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\7

Name : All Control Panel Items
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0


PS C:\> $Desktop.Items() | ?{$_.Name -match 'Panel$'} | %{$_.GetFolder.Items()} | %{$_.GetFolder.Items() | select Name, Type, Path | fl}
>>                                                                                                     

Name : Power Options
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\5\::{025A5937-A6BE-4686-A844-36FE4BEC8B6D}

Name : Windows Defender Firewall
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\5\::{4026492F-2F69-46B8-B9BF-5654FC07E423}

Name : Backup and Restore (Windows 7)
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\5\::{B98A2BEA-7D42-4558-8BD1-832F41BAC6FD}

Name : System
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\5\::{BB06C0E4-D293-4F75-8A90-CB05B6477EEE}

Name : Security and Maintenance
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\5\::{BB64F8A7-BEE7-4E1A-AB8D-7D8273F7FDB6}

Name : Administrative Tools
Type : System Folder
Path : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools

Name : Work Folders
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\5\::{ECDB0924-4208-451E-8EE0-373C0956DE16}

Name : File History
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\5\::{F6B6E965-E9B2-444B-9286-10C9152EDBC5}

Name : Storage Spaces
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\5\::{F942C606-0914-47AB-BE56-1321B8035096}

Name : Flash Player (32-bit)
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\{FF5B614E-7398-4596-B3F6-0C41283DA1AD}





Name : Network and Sharing Center
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\3\::{8E908FC9-BECC-40F6-915B-F4CA0E70D03D}

Name : Internet Options
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\3\::{A3DD4F92-658A-410F-84FD-6FBBBEF2FFFE}

Name : Intel® PROSet/Wireless Tools
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\3\::{F93169C3-1E48-45E0-92F7-D91B418B618A}





Name : Power Options
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\2\::{025A5937-A6BE-4686-A844-36FE4BEC8B6D}

Name : Touchpad
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\2\::{3EA22083-D5BF-411B-A6D6-A27541794266}

Name : Windows Mobility Center
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\2\::{5EA4F148-308C-46D7-98A9-49041B1DD468}

Name : Tablet PC Settings
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\2\::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}

Name : AutoPlay
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\2\::{9C60DE1E-E5FC-40F4-A487-460851A8D915}

Name : Devices and Printers
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\2\::{A8A91A66-3A7D-4424-8D24-04E180695C7A}

Name : Energy Star
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\2\::{AE37A7F8-8AEC-477A-BB4C-584B8000C34E}

Name : Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\2\::{E342F0FE-FF1C-4C41-BE37-A0271FC90396}

Name : Sound
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\2\::{F2DDFC82-8F12-4CDD-B7DC-D4FE1425AA4D}

Name : Pen and Touch
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\2\::{F82DF8F7-8B9F-442E-A48C-818EA735FF9B}

Name : Audio Control
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\{F82E749F-088E-4936-995E-BF5E4B8B81CA}

Name : Intel® Graphics Settings
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\{9D0F8984-3EF6-4F51-B2FF-131D8CD11831}





Name : Default Programs
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\8\::{17CD9488-1228-4B2F-88CE-4298E93E0966}

Name : Programs and Features
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\8\::{7B81BE6A-CE2B-4676-A29E-EB907A5126C5}





Name : Credential Manager
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\9\::{1206F5F1-0569-412C-8FEC-3204630DFB70}

Name : User Accounts
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\9\::{60632754-C523-4B62-B45C-4172DA012619}





Name : Taskbar and Navigation
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\1\::{0DF44EAA-FF21-4412-828E-260A8728E7F1}

Name : File Explorer Options
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\1\::{6DFD7C5C-2451-11D3-A299-00C04F8EF6AF}

Name : Fonts
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\1\Fonts

Name : Ease of Access Center
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\1\::{D555645E-D4F8-4C29-A827-D93C859C4F2A}





Name : Region
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\6\::{62D8ED13-C9D0-4CE8-A914-47DD628FB1B0}

Name : Date and Time
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\6\::{E2E7934B-DCE5-43C4-9576-7FE4F75E7480}





Name : Speech Recognition
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\7\::{58E3C745-D971-4081-9034-86E34B30836A}

Name : Ease of Access Center
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\7\::{D555645E-D4F8-4C29-A827-D93C859C4F2A}





Name : Power Options
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{025A5937-A6BE-4686-A844-36FE4BEC8B6D}

Name : Taskbar and Navigation
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{0DF44EAA-FF21-4412-828E-260A8728E7F1}

Name : Credential Manager
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{1206F5F1-0569-412C-8FEC-3204630DFB70}

Name : Default Programs
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{17CD9488-1228-4B2F-88CE-4298E93E0966}

Name : RemoteApp and Desktop Connections
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{241D7C96-F8BF-4F85-B01F-E2B043341A4B}

Name : Touchpad
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{3EA22083-D5BF-411B-A6D6-A27541794266}

Name : Windows Defender Firewall
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{4026492F-2F69-46B8-B9BF-5654FC07E423}

Name : Phone and Modem
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{40419485-C444-4567-851A-2DD7BFA1684D}

Name : Speech Recognition
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{58E3C745-D971-4081-9034-86E34B30836A}

Name : Windows Mobility Center
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{5EA4F148-308C-46D7-98A9-49041B1DD468}

Name : User Accounts
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{60632754-C523-4B62-B45C-4172DA012619}

Name : Region
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{62D8ED13-C9D0-4CE8-A914-47DD628FB1B0}

Name : Mouse
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{6C8EEC18-8D75-41B2-A177-8831D59D2D50}

Name : File Explorer Options
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{6DFD7C5C-2451-11D3-A299-00C04F8EF6AF}

Name : Keyboard
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{725BE8F7-668E-4C7B-8F90-46BDB0936430}

Name : Device Manager
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{74246BFC-4C96-11D0-ABEF-0020AF6B0B7A}

Name : Programs and Features
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{7B81BE6A-CE2B-4676-A29E-EB907A5126C5}

Name : Tablet PC Settings
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}

Name : Indexing Options
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{87D66A43-7B11-4A28-9811-C86EE395ACF7}

Name : Network and Sharing Center
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{8E908FC9-BECC-40F6-915B-F4CA0E70D03D}

Name : AutoPlay
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{9C60DE1E-E5FC-40F4-A487-460851A8D915}

Name : Sync Center
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{9C73F5E5-7AE7-4E32-A8E8-8D23B85255BF}

Name : Recovery
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{9FE63AFD-59CF-4419-9775-ABCC3849F861}

Name : Internet Options
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{A3DD4F92-658A-410F-84FD-6FBBBEF2FFFE}

Name : Devices and Printers
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{A8A91A66-3A7D-4424-8D24-04E180695C7A}

Name : Energy Star
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{AE37A7F8-8AEC-477A-BB4C-584B8000C34E}

Name : Color Management
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{B2C761C6-29BC-4F19-9251-E6195265BAF1}

Name : Backup and Restore (Windows 7)
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{B98A2BEA-7D42-4558-8BD1-832F41BAC6FD}

Name : System
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{BB06C0E4-D293-4F75-8A90-CB05B6477EEE}

Name : Security and Maintenance
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{BB64F8A7-BEE7-4E1A-AB8D-7D8273F7FDB6}

Name : Fonts
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\Fonts

Name : Troubleshooting
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{C58C4893-3BE0-4B45-ABB5-A63E4B8C8651}

Name : Administrative Tools
Type : System Folder
Path : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools

Name : Ease of Access Center
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{D555645E-D4F8-4C29-A827-D93C859C4F2A}

Name : Date and Time
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{E2E7934B-DCE5-43C4-9576-7FE4F75E7480}

Name : Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{E342F0FE-FF1C-4C41-BE37-A0271FC90396}

Name : Work Folders
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{ECDB0924-4208-451E-8EE0-373C0956DE16}

Name : Sound
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{F2DDFC82-8F12-4CDD-B7DC-D4FE1425AA4D}

Name : File History
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{F6B6E965-E9B2-444B-9286-10C9152EDBC5}

Name : Pen and Touch
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{F82DF8F7-8B9F-442E-A48C-818EA735FF9B}

Name : Intel® PROSet/Wireless Tools
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{F93169C3-1E48-45E0-92F7-D91B418B618A}

Name : Storage Spaces
Type : System Folder
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{F942C606-0914-47AB-BE56-1321B8035096}

Name : Audio Control
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\{F82E749F-088E-4936-995E-BF5E4B8B81CA}

Name : Flash Player (32-bit)
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\{FF5B614E-7398-4596-B3F6-0C41283DA1AD}

Name : Intel® Graphics Settings
Type :
Path : ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\{9D0F8984-3EF6-4F51-B2FF-131D8CD11831}
```

Comment: It is really just pointers because everything is located in a real location

Comment: That's an over-simplification. There is no 'loccation'  that corresponds to the **This PC** folder. It only exists as a construct of the Shell.

Comment: @John: Added some **PowerShell** code that reveals the nature of the Shell namespace.

Comment: I do not see using Windows Explorer as being this difficult. "This PC" is part of the pointer system. "My PC" or "Computer Name" is the real file system Truly - I never had to use Powershell to see where my files are. YMMV.

Comment: LOL. nobody said using **Explorer** was difficult --- you missed the point. But anyone who spends any time in technical forums knows there is frequent confusion regarding the folders under **This PC** and the differences between the root **Desktop** and the user's **Desktop** folder. These are all part of the namespace. "Pointer system" is a vague and simplistic term -- perhaps sufficient to convey a basic understanding of the foldrs under **This PC** but not much else. Namespace & virtual folder are precise terms. Why the aversion to the standard  nomencalture and definitions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103999/discussion-between-john-and-keith-miller).

Comment: No, thank you. I'm low vision & have to zoom the browser. The frames  (or whatever - not an HTML person) on the chat page don't play well with zoom.

Comment: Thanks, that explains quite a bit of what's going on here, and the origin of the structure the explorer shows when you "Show all folders" which essentially appears to mean "use the root of the shell namespace, known as the Desktop, as the root of the tree view (Quick Access notwithstanding)". Still not really explained: what the explorer is choosing to show when this option is not checked (which includes Control Panel and the user profile folder, neither of which shows with "Show all folders")